# How to create this type json in codeigniter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

```
variations=[
{"property_id":504, "value":"8", "is_available":true, "price": 100},
{"property_id":504, "value":"12", "is_available":true, "price": 105},
{"property_id":513, "value":"Pepperoni", "is_available":true},
{"property_id":513, "value":"Mushrooms", "is_available":true}
]&diameter_scale=341&custom_property_names={"513":"Topping"}
```

how to convert my array in to the json in this type

```
$insert_variation_data = array(
    'property_id'   => $_POST["property_id"][$ix],
    'value'         => $_POST["values"][$ix],
    'is_available'  => true,
    'scale'         => $_POST["scale"][$ix],
    'price'         => $_POST["price"][$ix]  
);
```

I have array then how it covert in above variation but i think above mentioned json is not valid but i want same conversion

Comment: variations=[
{"property_id":504, "value":"8", "is_available":true, "price": 100 "diameter_scale":341,},
{"property_id":504, "value":"12", "is_available":true, "price": 105,"diameter_scale":341},
 
 ]

Comment: still getting error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Create a multidimensional array.

```
 $insert_variation_data = array(
           array(
                'property_id'   => $_POST["property_id"][$ix],
                'value'         => $_POST["values"][$ix],
                'is_available'  => true,
                'scale'         => $_POST["scale"][$ix],
                'price'         => $_POST["price"][$ix]  
            )
);
```

and

```
echo json_decode($insert_variation_data);
```

Comment: variations=[
{"property_id":504, "value":"8", "is_available":true, "price": 100},
{"property_id":504, "value":"12", "is_available":true, "price": 105},
{"property_id":513, "value":"Pepperoni", "is_available":true},
{"property_id":513, "value":"Mushrooms", "is_available":true}
]&diameter_scale=341&custom_property_names={"513":"Topping"}

Answer (score 0):

@kanishka has given a proper answer but we have do it using endcode. For example let say I have a function test in my controller like below one

```
function test()
    {
         $insert_variation_data = array(
                'property_id'   => 'x',
                'value'         => 'y',
                'is_available'  => true,
                'scale'         => 'z',
                'price'         => 'm'  
            );
         $insert_variation_data[] = array(
                'property_id'   => 'a',
                'value'         => 'b',
                'is_available'  => true,
                'scale'         => 'c',
                'price'         => 'd'  
            );
         print_r(json_encode(array($insert_variation_data)));
    }
```

this will give us an out put

```
[{"property_id":"x","value":"y","is_available":true,"scale":"z","price":"m","0":{"property_id":"a","value":"b","is_available":true,"scale":"c","price":"d"}}]
```

And if you want this response in an ajax or some other. Please add those code where you have to use it so we can help out more.